# Sharing files between Kaggle notebooks

Tags: kaggle

I've just submitted a solution to a Kaggle competition. I did all the work locally on my laptop and then subsequently uploaded the relevant files to Kaggle.

On my machine, I had a folder containing the data and two separate notebooks for data analysis and model fitting. The data analysis notebook exported the cleaned data which I then imported in the second notebook.

I uploaded the notebooks to Kaggle, but had to import the cleaned data by hand from my computer as I couldn't see a way of sharing files across the two notebooks.

Is there a better way of doing this? Or do Kaggle expect you to do everything in a single notebook?

Answer (score 1):

You can use another notebook output as a source. Typically the data eng. notebook take raw data as input and output transformed data. The modelling notebooks, takes the second notebook as a source, using its output.

Generally speaking, you are better off asking these questions on Kaggle directly.